Getting GamesClient instance from Google Play Games SDK v2
The current Google Play Games SDK  (v2:20.1.2) defines GamesClient interface, which I need for getSettingsIntent. However, I cannot figure out the way to get an instance of it. For other interfaces, like LeaderboardClient, AchievementClient there are static get methods in PlayGames, but no getGamesClient method there. Any idea?

According to the documentation, PlayGames is a class and not an interface and there is no method to get the GamesClient there.
- static AchievementsClient 
getAchievementsClient(Activity activity)
Returns a new instance of AchievementsClient for use in an Activity.
- static EventsClient   
getEventsClient(Activity activity)
Returns a new instance of EventsClient for use in an Activity.
- static GamesSignInClient  
getGamesSignInClient(Activity activity)
Returns a new instance of GamesSignInClient for use in an Activity.
- static LeaderboardsClient 
getLeaderboardsClient(Activity activity)
Returns a new instance of LeaderboardsClient for use in an Activity.
- static PlayerStatsClient  
getPlayerStatsClient(Activity activity)
Returns a new instance of PlayerStatsClient for use in an Activity.
- static PlayersClient  
getPlayersClient(Activity activity)
Returns a new instance of PlayersClient for use in an Activity.
- static RecallClient   
getRecallClient(Activity activity)
Returns a new instance of RecallClient for use in an Activity.
- static SnapshotsClient    
getSnapshotsClient(Activity activity)
Returns a new instance of SnapshotsClient for use in an Activity.

GamesClient is an interface you need to implement yourself and add your own logic to the methods declared there.

GamesClient cannot be SDK client's own interface, firstly because SDK documentation doesn't say that, secondly because the methods of this interface involve features available only to SDK, but not to its client.

@cyanide - I didn't say GamesClient was the SDK's client's own interface. It's an interface you need to implement that is exposed by the Games SDK v2. Also, what features that it exposes are only available to the SDK? I.E. setGravityForPopups is not something that only a SDK can do. I would urge you to also notice how the interface is called GamesClient hinting that it is something the client is supposed to implement. How would the SDK know which view to set for popups? Read the documentation I linked to.
Also, downvoting an answer which tries to help you is in no way beneficial.
